# Refresh rate and FPS

Tags: java, refresh, frame-rate

I am making a 2D game in Java. I made a UI slider which controls the FPS of the game. Is there any reason for the FPS slider to be able to go above 200 FPS, when most computer monitors only have a refresh rate of about 60 Hz? Also why would you want an FPS rating higher than your monitor's refresh rate? I have read that visual data is lost when your FPS is higher than your refresh rate, which makes sense. Most games I have seen have FPS sliders that can go much higher than 60 FPS, so I am a little confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say it's a high-end game which requires good hardware. Some players would want to try and see how many FPS they can get, using the game as a benchmark.
Other than that, 120 Hz (or even 200 Hz) monitors are getting popular, so it could make sense.

What's usually even better than having a slider in the first place is using VSync to lock your framerate to the monitor's refresh rate. If that's not possible because of faulty drivers, hardware, or user override, just go for a reasonable default like 60 FPS.

Comment: Thank you. Congratulations on your first answer at SO for 3 years :O